How to load livephoto from `PhotosPickerItem` with `Transferable`
I can load PHLivephoto with loadTransferable(type: PHLivePhoto.self).
But I could not load livephotos from my own Transferable type. For example, loadTransferable(type: LivephotoTrasferable.self)
in which the LivephotoTrasferable is as below:
struct LivephotoTrasferable: Transferable {
    static var transferRepresentation: some TransferRepresentation {
        FileRepresentation(contentType: .livePhoto) { item in
            SentTransferredFile(item.url)
        } importing: { file in
            print("livephoto!")
            return Self.init(url: file.file)
        }
    
        // ...other representations
    }
    
    var url: URL
}

I hope to manage the import and export logic of Live Photos through a unified approach, namely, LivephotoTrasferable, instead of the current process where I first extract the image URL with loadTransferable(type: LivephotoTrasferable.self), then extract the Live Photo with loadTransferable(type: PHLivePhoto.self). LivephotoTrasferable.self is also used in the drag & drop logic.
The whole code snippet is:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection: PhotosPickerItem?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            PhotosPicker(selection: $selection) {
                Text("Import image")
            }
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            .onChange(of: selection) { oldValue, newValue in
                if let item = newValue {
                    self.loadTransferable(item)
                    self.selection = nil
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    func loadTransferable(_ item: PhotosPickerItem) {
        Task {
            let livephoto = try? await item.loadTransferable(type: PHLivePhoto.self)
            let livephoto2 = try? await item.loadTransferable(type: LivephotoTrasferable.self)
            print(livephoto != nil, livephoto2 != nil) // true, false
        }
    }
}

struct LivephotoTrasferable: Transferable {
    static var transferRepresentation: some TransferRepresentation {
        FileRepresentation(contentType: .livePhoto) { item in
            SentTransferredFile(item.url)
        } importing: { file in
            print("livephoto!")
            return Self.init(url: file.file)
        }
    }
    
    var url: URL
}



Why not just use PHLivePhoto directly? What is the point of creating your own Transferable?

@Sweeper To better streamline the management of importing and exporting live photos, such as drag/drop, photosPicker.

Have you tried setting the preferredItemEncoding in PhotosPicker. As far as I know LivePhotos are only available when you import HEIC files, which would be .current. At least in my case the default value imports JPG and no Live Photos.

The documentation for .livePhoto says:

The identifier for this type is com.apple.live-photo.

But on iOS live photos seem to be of type com.apple.live-photo-bundle.
So if we define:
extension UTType {
    static var livePhotoBundle: UTType {
        UTType("com.apple.live-photo-bundle")!
    }
}

And use it as:
FileRepresentation(contentType: .livePhotoBundle) { item in
        SentTransferredFile(item.url)
    } importing: { file in
        print("livephoto!")
        return Self.init(url: file.file)
    }

Then live photos can be imported on iOS.
